# PL/SQL errors during dynamic sql execution

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I have a PL/SQL Procedure that prints out a correct sql but once I call `EXECUTE`, I get an error that sql is not properly ended.

here is my procedure

```
procedure my_proc(p_first VARCHAR2, p_second NUMBER, p_third NUMBER DEFAULT NULL, p_fouth NUMBER DEFAULT NULL)
IS
str varchar2(3200);
v1 VARCHAR2(20);
v2 VARCHAR2(20);
v3 VARCHAR2(20);
str2 varchar2(1000);

begin

str2:='SELECT t2.c1,t2.c2,t2.c3 FROM ';

if p_third=3 then
        str:= 't1,t2,t3 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t3.c1 and t1.c1=p_first ;' ;
elsif p_third=2 then
        str:=' t1,t2,t4 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t4.c1 and t2.c1=p_second ;' ;
else
        str:='t2 where t2.c1=p_second ;';
end if;

str2:=str2 || str;

dbms_output.put_line(str2);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  str2 into v1,v2,v3;

--dbms_output.put_line(v1||','||v2||','||v3);

end;
```

When I comment out `EXECUTE` statement, I get

```
SELECT t2.c1,t2.c2,t2.c3 FROM t1,t2,t4 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t4.c1 and t2.c1=p_second;
```

which looks fine, so I am not sure why execution gives me `SQL command not properly ended.

I tried removing semicolon at the end of the sql but then I get `ORA-00904: "p_second": invalid identifier`
.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot pass parameters this way

```
't1,t2,t3 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t3.c1 and t1.c1=p_first ;'
```

change to

```
't1,t2,t3 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t3.c1 and t1.c1='''||p_first ||''';'
```

Comment: It would surprise me if this would work. The dynamic statement must not contain the semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting is because the dynamic statement should not have a semicolon at the end. That is a client statement separator, not part of the statement itself, and execute immediate only accepts a single statement. (Whether you get "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" or "ORA-00911: invalid character" depends on your Oracle version).

So the first fix is to change your code to remove those:

```
if p_third=3 then
        str:= 't1,t2,t3 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t3.c1 and t1.c1=p_first' ;
elsif p_third=2 then
        str:=' t1,t2,t4 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t4.c1 and t2.c1=p_second' ;
else
        str:='t2 where t2.c1=p_second';
end if;
```

But when those statements are executed they are in a separate SQL context that has no visibility or knowledge of the PL/SQL variables and procedure arguments. It will try, and fail, to interpret `p_first` or `p_second` as column names, and they are unlikely to exist (and even if they do it won't do what you expect).

You can concatenate in the arguments directly, as @are suggested (but still without the semicolons):

```
        str:= 't1,t2,t3 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t3.c1 and t1.c1=''' || p_first || '''';
        str:=' t1,t2,t4 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t4.c1 and t2.c1=' || p_second;
        str:='t2 where t2.c1=' || p_second;
```

etc., which gets slightly more complicated with other data types as you need to handle dates properly and so on.

But it would be better to use bind variables; which means have separate `execute immediate` calls so you can supply the relevant bind value for each generated query. Something like:

```
begin

  str := 'SELECT t2.c1,t2.c2,t2.c3 FROM ';

  if p_third=3 then
    str := str || 't1,t2,t3 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t3.c1 and t1.c1=:p_first';
    dbms_output.put_line(str);
    execute immediate str into v1, v2, v3 using p_first;
  elsif p_third=2 then
    str := str || ' t1,t2,t4 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t4.c1 and t2.c1=:p_second';
    dbms_output.put_line(str);
    execute immediate str into v1, v2, v3 using p_second;
  else
    str := str || 't2 where t2.c1=:p_second';
    dbms_output.put_line(str);
    execute immediate str into v1, v2, v3 using p_second;
  end if;

  --dbms_output.put_line(v1||','||v2||','||v3);

end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from Alex's answer I would recommend ANSI join syntax:

```
begin

  str := 'SELECT t2.c1,t2.c2,t2.c3 FROM ';

  if p_third=3 then
    str := str || 't1 JOIN t2 ON t1.c1=t2.c1 JOIN t3 ON t2.c1=t3.c1 WHERE t1.c1=:p_first';
    dbms_output.put_line(str);
    execute immediate str into v1, v2, v3 using p_first;
  elsif p_third=2 then
    str := str || ' t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.c1=t2.c1 JOIN t4 ON t2.c1=t4.c1 where t2.c1=:p_second';
    dbms_output.put_line(str);
    execute immediate str into v1, v2, v3 using p_second;
  else
    str := str || 't2 where t2.c1=:p_second';
    dbms_output.put_line(str);
    execute immediate str into v1, v2, v3 using p_second;
  end if;

  --dbms_output.put_line(v1||','||v2||','||v3);

end;
```